# C# how to check if database is not busy?

Tags: c#, sql-server

My class has a couple of methods going on. The first one is creating a database, that's done. Then, creates stored procedures that is being read from a sql file. then detach that DB. Now it seems that my store procedure query is taking a while to finish and my method to detach is being invoked while the database is busy. So how do I tell if the database is idle. The exception goes "cannot detach the database because it is currently in use"

Methods:

```
void CreateStoredProcedures(string type)
        {
            string spLocation = File.ReadAllText("CreateStoredProcedures.sql");
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString + ";database=" + type + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));            

            try
            {
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(spLocation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

bool DetachBackup(string type)
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
            command.CommandText = @"sys.sp_detach_db '" + type + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((conn.State == ConnectionState.Open))
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Click event:

```
private void btnFullBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Starting full backup...";
            Execute("FULL");
            progressBar.Value = 20;                       
            lblStatus.Text = "Copying tables...";
            progressBar.Value = 60;            
            CopyTables("FULL");
            progressBar.Value = 70;
            lblStatus.Text = "Creating stored procedures...";
            CreateStoredProcedures("FULL");

            progressBar.Value = 80;
            CheckDBSize(newBackupLocation, "FULL");

            progressBar.Value = 100;
            MessageBox.Show("Backup was created successfully", "",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);            

            lblStatus.Text = "Done";
            progressBar.Value = 0;

            if (DetachBackup("FULL") == false)
            {
                DetachBackup("FULL");
            }
        }
```

Comment: For a start do `using(var conn = new SqlConnection ... ) {` for all your connections.

Comment: As you are using DateTime.Now to get a timestamp you might detach a different database if you run this close to midnight.

Comment: @rene it didn't help, unfortunately.  No worries, this program won't be run near midnight.

Comment: Does your connectionstring have an initial catalog?

Comment: @rene No it doesn't. Let me try to add it in.

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do? If you want a database backup why not simply issue a backup command? Why are you creating a new database based on the current date and then promptly detaching it? What real world scenario would this be required for?

Comment: @SeanLange because there is a function that will select a specific conditions of data to be backed up.

Comment: So what you are doing is creating a brand new database each time you want to make a backup, populating with a copy of data from the current database and then detaching it? That seems like a way overly complicated process. But I suppose if the database is really huge that might be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't think of it as the database being "busy", but the error message uses good verbage: **in use**.  To find out if the database is currently in use, the most accurate way would be to find out if any sessions have any lock in the particular database, by querying `sys.dm_tran_locks`.  Here is a helper function to return a `bool` whether or not the database is in use:

```
    bool IsDatabaseInUse(string databaseName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("... your connection string ..."))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
            sqlCmd.CommandText =
                @"select count(*)
                from sys.dm_tran_locks
                where resource_database_id = db_id(@database_name);";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@database_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128)
            {
                Value = databaseName
            });

            sqlConnection.Open();
            int sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

            if (sessionCount > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

*Note: Make sure your initial catalog in your connection string isn't the database you're trying to make "not in use", as that'll put your current session in the context of the database, not allowing that operation to complete*

Comment: And what is next if the OP runs this and it returns `true`?

Comment: @rene the OP would have to decide what to do.  Valid options here would be to either 1) wait until it is no longer in use by polling or 2) kill the sessions that currently have locks in the database.

Comment: I'll probably kill the sessions.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay You would need to enumerate the sessions and then call `KILL` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) for them.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are it's getting hung on its own connection. sp_detach_db's MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188031.aspx has the following suggestion under the section Obtain Exclusive Access:

```
USE master; 
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET SINGLE_USER;
```

You're DetachBackup method will have connect to master, run the ALTER and the sp_detach_db procedure.

Comment: That won't always be the case, and you can't rely on that assumption with a database.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't closing the connection in your CreateStoredProcedures method. Put using statements in like I've shown here and it should fix the problem. ([Brief using statement explanation from Microsoft.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx))

Try this code for your methods:

```
    void CreateStoredProcedures(string type)
    {
        string spLocation = File.ReadAllText("CreateStoredProcedures.sql");
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString + ";database=" + type + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")))
        {
            try
            {
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(spLocation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        } // End of using, connection will always close when you reach this point.
    }

    bool DetachBackup(string type)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"sys.sp_detach_db '" + type + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'", conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        } // End of using, connection will always close when you reach this point.
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have my detach method  separated from the create stored proc method.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay not sure if I understand that comment. This answer consist of two methods as well?

Comment: Unfortunately this approach did not solve the issue. It still shows the database busy when trying to run the detach method.

Comment: You cannot detach a database you are connected to.  Use the SQLDMO library for this sort of thing.